# QNAMaker Bot cannot be Tested in Site

Tags: azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I can't test my QNAMaker bot. The error message says:

"Oops!! Something went wrong.
Please try again. If this error persists, please provide details via the feedback menu."

[image]

The bot is still working on teams. I just can't test it on the QNAMaker.ai Site.

I already tried restarting the app service but still, the error exists.

Comment: Does the associated QnA service in Azure still exist? Did it get deleted or otherwise change?

Comment: Hi, Qna Service still exist in Azure. I already restarted the app service and cleared my browser cached but the issue still exist.

Comment: How about deleting and starting fresh with a new Azure QnA service? You should download your KB beforehand so you can import it at a later point.